# Exchange Data between GIS and CAD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, microstation

I'm a student engineer and I'm preparing my final project study about the problems of exchanging Data between CAD and Gis in general - particularly Microstation and ArcGIS  - and the changes that affect the files during their transfer: color's changing, thickness, position...

Moreover, the causes of these changes and how we can proceed to reduce the loss of information when transferring files.

Have you any information about this?

Comment: FME Desktop does not have any issues converting DGN to ArcGIS shapefile or geodatabase and vice versa - have you considered that? We have project critical data that requires conversion daily.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Unlike discussion sites, our purpose is to catalog focused questions with specific answers; as such, this is not a good source of primary/initial research (unless you want to mine the Q&A database looking for CAD/GIS issues).

Comment: I second the FME solution.  Of course, I stopped looking once I discovered it a few years ago, but it's the only solution I found to batch convert multiple formats (including CAD) cleanly.

Comment: Thank you, yes actually I heard good things about FME desktop, I'll use it to solve my exchanging problems :)

Comment: @Vince Yes vince, I'm searching exactly the most common problems that affects files during transfer